# how do I get rid of "^M" in data I have scraped from a website?

Tags: python, html

I have data that looks like this:

```
"1964   iwanttoholdyourhand beatles



^M

oh yeah, i'll tell you something
i think you'll understand
when i'll say that something
i wanna hold your hand
i wanna hold your hand
i wanna hold your hand

oh please, say to me
you'll let me be your man
and please, say to me
you'll let me hold your hand
i'll let me hold your hand
i wanna hold your hand"
```

and I'm trying to get rid of the ^M, so I tried using a re.sub but that doesn't find it - I think is some special character and not actually a "^" and "M" next to each other.  any ideas on how to remove it?
Thanks!

Comment: The "^M" character is generally referred to as "\r" in regexes or strings. It's a "carriage return", originally picked as the character that would tell a printer to return the "carriage" - the thing carrying the print head - back to the left edge of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

^M is used to represent the carriage return character in many editors.  You would typically type Ctrl + M to generate that character in those editors.

Python represents this as `'\r'`, as do most programming languages.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a windows vs. unix line endings issue. Unix uses \n (newline), windows uses \r\n instead (carriage return + newline). You want to remove the \r (ASCII codepoint 13); you can do it in python (without even using regexes I think), or you can simply run the fromdos program on your file. Many unix tools represent \r as ^M (M being the 13th letter of the alphabet).

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return) is a nice starting point.